# My system boots directly into Windows 8 and I can't see the grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu from a bootable DVD, created the partition using the installer and went through all the necessary steps but when I restarted, the computer went directly into Windows 8.

Is there something simple that I'm doing wrong? Like holding down a certain key when restarting?

Comment: Can I delete the partition I created from Windows 8 and then re-install Ubuntu?  Will that put my files at risk?

Comment: I was able to successfully restore my grub.  Thanks so much Arno.

Answer (score 0):

try running the [Boot repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) to restore your grub